# Embed collection of form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm stuck with an embed collection of form.

I have a Holiday form consisting of three fields : a name, a begin and an end.
Note that begin and end are managed by [Bootstrap date-time picker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

[image: Holiday Form]

Then I have a Grade Form consisting of some fields and a collection of Holiday Form.
The javascript part to add or delete a Holiday Form works fine.

[image: Grade From]

As you can see in this image, the begin and end icon are not shown. But this is not all, the date-time picker doesn't works.
I have find out that the data-prototype given by symfony is not complete, some classes are missing.

Should I add an option or something else in my Types to make it works ?

EDIT :

My GradeType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('campus', 'entity',
        [
        'class' => 'Ent\HomeBundle\Entity\Campus',
        'property' => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('c');
                if ($this->controller->getCurrentUser()->getGroup()->getRole() == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
                    $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('c', ':campuses'))
                       ->setParameter('campuses', $this->controller->getCurrentUser()->getCampuses()->toArray());
                }
                return $qb;
            }
        ]
    );
    $builder->add('school', 'entity', [
        'class' => 'Ent\HomeBundle\Entity\School',
        'property' => 'name'
        ]
    );
    $builder->add('holidays', 'collection',
        [
        'type'         => new HolidayType($this->controller),
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false
        ]
        );
}
```

My HolidayType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('begin', new DatePickerType(), ['help' => 'Only the day and the month will be used']);
    $builder->add('end', new DatePickerType(), [
        'required' => false,
        'help' => 'Only the day and the month will be used',
        ]
    );

     $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, array($this, 'isEndValid'));
}
```

Comment: show us some code please

Comment: Well, not knowing anything about what is going on because you haven't provided code, it is hard to answer...

Comment: I have posted too soon inadvertently, sorry. I've edited.

Comment: What classes do you mean with "some classes are missing", I'm thinking CSS-classes?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not precising it. For exemple, I have `<i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>` where I should have `<i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" class="icon-calendar"></i>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datepicker is not working because you add the datepicker fields via javascript. You have to call something like

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'
});
```

when you add the new rows from the prototype. By calling .datetimepicker() you enable the datepicker for the selected field.

Concerning the missing classes You have to post the content of the DatePickerType.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works fine. I totally forgot to activate the datetimepicker. Actually the missing classes was my fault. This issue is fully resolved :)